# Random Pick From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to make a website where it selects random things from arrays to make a sentence. It is supposed to pick a random item from `objectArray` and display it through a `div` with `document.getElementById()`

Code

```
<script>
    var objectArray = ["computer", "iphone", "duck", "candle", "oven", "sofa", "curtain", "blanket", "star", "piano", "turtle", "fluffiness", "door", "pillow", "funny face", "lamp", "healthy heart", "rainbow", "lamp", "clock", "coat", "just luck", "stop sign", "window"];
    var randObject = objectArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * objectArray.length)];

    document.getElementById("Objecto").innerHTML = "randObject";    
</script>

<center>
    <div id="Objecto"></div>
</center>
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the element's `innerHTML` to the string literal `"randObject"` instead of the contents of the variable `randObject`. Use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("Objecto").innerHTML = randObject;
```

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
var objectArray = ["computer", "iphone", "duck", "candle", "oven", "sofa", "curtain", "blanket", "star", "piano", "turtle", "fluffiness", "door", "pillow", "funny face", "lamp", "healthy heart", "rainbow", "lamp", "clock", "coat", "just luck", "stop sign", "window"];
var randObject = objectArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * objectArray.length)];

document.getElementById("Objecto").innerHTML = randObject;
```

```html
<center>
    <div id="Objecto"></div>
</center>
```